# Aligning the Concatenated String to Right in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, alignment

I have this input by using this code

```
SELECT 
    Sales Territory Region, 
    CONCAT(SUM(Extended Amount), 3, ' US Dollars') AS 'Total sales'
```

[Result of code - not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FnjP.png)

and I want this output with US Dollar in alignment

[Expected output with US Dollar right aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEIaD.png)

Comment: you know that SQL only deals with how data is stored and retrieved? displaying the data is responsibility of the executable providing the UI.

Comment: @Psi Yes I said same to my senior but he told me no you are wrong that leads me to post it here

Comment: then show him my comment… it’s quite hard to believe, though

Comment: @UsamaAli  - Post the bloody data as something that's a least copy'n'pastable instead of graphics.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Psi, this is a display issue and should be handled by the application or display layer. That being said, you *can* do something in SQL to get close to this, but it only works if you are using a fixed width font (a font in which every character has the same width).

The way to do it is figure out how wide the result column will be - for the sake of demonstration let's say 75 characters. Now all that is needed is to prepend as many spaces as necessary to get the concatenated value to be 75. This will not look correct in SSMS unless you have changed the default font to be a fixed-width font... run the sample and then paste the result into a program that uses a fixed-width font, or a program that let's you choose a font. I ran this sample and pasted it into Notepad++ and it is indeed correctly right-aligned.

```sql
-- make a table variable with sample data
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Sales_Territory_Region VARCHAR(50), Extended_Amount DECIMAL(10,3));

-- populate some sample data
INSERT INTO @Data(Sales_Territory_Region, Extended_Amount) 
VALUES ('US', 9061000.58), ('JP', 1977844.86), ('XX', 3000.83);

-- create a right-aligned column
SELECT Sales_Territory_Region, 
   CONCAT(REPLICATE(' ', 50 - LEN(CONCAT(Extended_Amount, ' US Dollars'))), Extended_Amount, ' US Dollars') AS [Total] 
FROM @Data
```

Again, this will only look correct if you are using a fixed-width font! Also, just because you can do something like this does not mean it is an ideal approach - this is a display issue and not a data issue, so it should most likely be handled by the front end.